# occurred configuring project ':app'. > Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: react-native

I would like to start my first application react-native but when i write in the command line "react-native run-android" it say :

#### What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
 > javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: nobody knows, i think

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this same issue and it was due to having two versions of JDK installed v8 & v9. By removing v9, I was able to resolve the issue (Mac User).

If you only have version 9 installed, I would remove it and try v8.

Navigate to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and remove the v9 directory

```
sudo rm -rf {yourVersionName}.jdk
```

You should have v8 in that directory. If not you will need to install it.

Comment: I only had jdk 9 and got this error. Looks like you need jdk 8.

Comment: Same issue for me. Uninstalled java9 and installed java8 and all working.

Answer (score 1):

if you use windows env and use different java version change java version at system path as java 8.

[image: java env example]