# gradlew app:dependencies command is not working

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting errors when running command `gradlew app:dependencies`. I want to check which dependency are making conflict. Because my project is not compiling after adding twitter dependency. So i disabled twitter dependency and tried to check which of module if using `google.gms package.` So i can exclude that.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

Then tried changing version of gradle wrapper or gradle plugin. got this error.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler

Then after some change again by searching this error.

> Could not determine java version from '9.0.4'.

**I can run app but i can not see dependency tree.**

**What is this, i am stuck of hours :(**

app level `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amelio"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationId + "-v" + versionCode + "(" + versionName + ")")
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-T"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            versionNameSuffix "-R"
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility rootProject.ext.sourceCompatibilityVersion
        targetCompatibility rootProject.ext.targetCompatibilityVersion
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

def SDP_VERSION = '1.0.5'
def PERCELER_VERSION = '1.1.10'

dependencies {
//    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.firebaseAuth
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
    }
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.supportAppcompatV7
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.supportRecyclerViewV7
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.supportV4
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.supportDesign
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.playServicesAuth
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.retrofit2ConverterGson
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.retrofit2
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.playServicesLocation
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.playServicesMaps
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.playServicesPlaces
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.firebaseMessaging
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.materialDatePicker
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
    implementation "com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:$SDP_VERSION"
    implementation "com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:$SDP_VERSION"
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.picasso
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.1'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.8'
//  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
    implementation "org.parceler:parceler-api:$PERCELER_VERSION"
    annotationProcessor "org.parceler:parceler:$PERCELER_VERSION"
    implementation rootProject.ext.dep.butterKnife
    annotationProcessor rootProject.ext.dep.butterKnifeCompiler
//    compile 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.7'
    implementation('com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.1')
//    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0@aar') {
//        transitive = true
//    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project level `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply from: rootProject.file('dependencies.gradle')

buildscript {
    ext.objectboxVersion = '1.5.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectboxVersion"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Wed May 16 15:37:31 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Another file `dependencies.gradle` which i use to define all dependency versions.

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
    minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    sourceCompatibilityVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibilityVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    SUPPORT_LIB_VER = '27.1.0'
    PLAY_SERVICES_VER = '15.0.0'
    FIREBASE_VER = '15.0.0'
    RX_BINDING_VER = '2.0.0'
    DAGGER2_VER = '2.11-rc2'
    BOLTS_VER = '1.4.0'
    RETROFIT_VER = "2.1.0"
    OKHTTP_VER = '3.0.1'
    BUTTER_KNIFE_VER = '8.5.1'

    dep = [
            // Google Support Library.
            supportV4              : "com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER",
            supportV4CoreUtils     : "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER",
            supportAppcompatV7     : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER",
            supportRecyclerViewV7  : "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}",
            supportCardViewV7      : "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}",
            supportGridLayoutV7    : "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}",
            supportAnnotations     : "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER",
            supportDesign          : "com.android.support:design:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}",
            supportVectorDrawable  : "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}",
            supportPercent         : "com.android.support:percent:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}",
            supportTransition      : "com.android.support:transition:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}",
            supportConstraintLayout: "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2",
            supportMultidex        : 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1',
            // Google Play Service.
            playServicesAds        : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${PLAY_SERVICES_VER}",
            playServicesAnalytics  : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${PLAY_SERVICES_VER}",
            playServicesVision     : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:${PLAY_SERVICES_VER}",
            playServicesMaps       : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${PLAY_SERVICES_VER}",
            playServicesPlaces     : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:${PLAY_SERVICES_VER}",
            playServicesAuth       : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${PLAY_SERVICES_VER}",
            playServicesLocation   : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${PLAY_SERVICES_VER}",
            // Google Firebase.
            firebaseCore           : "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${FIREBASE_VER}",
            firebaseAnalytics      : "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:${FIREBASE_VER}",
            firebaseAuth           : 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0',
            firebaseConfig         : "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:${FIREBASE_VER}",
            firebaseCrash          : "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${FIREBASE_VER}",
            firebaseMessaging      : "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${FIREBASE_VER}",
            firebaseInvites        : "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:${FIREBASE_VER}",
            firebasePerf           : "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:${FIREBASE_VER}",
            // Facebook.
            facebook               : 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0',
            facebookAudienceNetwork: 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.17.0',
            // JSON.
            gson                   : "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7",
            // Image.
//            fresco                 : "com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1",
//            glide                  : "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0",
//            lottie                 : 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.0.0-rc1',
            picasso                 : 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2',
//            adobeFoundation        : 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251',
//            adobeImage             : 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.3',
            // RxJava.
//            rxJava                 : 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0',
//            rxAndroid              : 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1',
//            rxRelay                : 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0',
//            rxBinding              : "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:${RX_BINDING_VER}",
//            rxBindingRecyclerViewV7: "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7:${RX_BINDING_VER}",
//            rxPermissions          : 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.4@aar',
            // View Binding.
            butterKnife            : "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${BUTTER_KNIFE_VER}",
            butterKnifeCompiler    : "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${BUTTER_KNIFE_VER}",
            // Dependency Injection.
//            dagger2                : "com.google.dagger:dagger:${DAGGER2_VER}",
//            dagger2Support         : "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${DAGGER2_VER}",
//            dagger2Compiler        : "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${DAGGER2_VER}",
            // Leak Detection.
            leakcanary             : 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1',
            leakcanaryNoOp         : 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1',
            // Custom View.
//            discreteScrollView     : 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.2.0',
            // ASYNC.
//            bolts                  : "com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:$BOLTS_VER",
            // BUS.
//            ottoBus                : 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6',
            // HTTP/HTTPS.
            retrofit2              : "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${RETROFIT_VER}",
            retrofit2ConverterGson : "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${RETROFIT_VER}",
//            retrofit2RxJava2Adapter: 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0',
            okhttp                 : "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$OKHTTP_VER",
//            okhttpMockWebServer    : "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:$OKHTTP_VER",
//            volley                 : 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0',
            // TESTING.
//            testJunit              : 'junit:junit:4.12',
//            testMockito            : 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9',
//            testEspressoCore       : 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
//            testRunner             : 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5',
            materialDatePicker     : 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.0'
    ]
}
```

searched a lot some of them are.

[I am having a difficulty with first time react-native run-android. The Error looks like this following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795885/i-am-having-a-difficulty-with-first-time-react-native-run-android-the-error-loo?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[occurred configuring project ':app'. > Failed to notify project evaluation listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415673/occurred-configuring-project-app-failed-to-notify-project-evaluation-liste?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893768/could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @PeterHaddad Tried already with 4.1 and 4.4 version

Comment: I'll try this peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating all dependencies worked for me.